# Search query from joined table in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

I have a books table that contains many subject on my subjects table (one-to-many relationship).

I tried to join my tables like this:

```
$book = Book::latest() 
    ->leftjoin('subjects', 'books.id', '=', 'subjects.book_id') 
    ->select('books.*', 'subjects.subject')
    ->where('subject', 'like', '%' .$search. '%')
    ->paginate(20);
```

I want a search query that will display the books having subjects matched form the `$search` variable. However, it keeps displaying a book redundantly depending on how many subjects of a book that matched on the $search variable since a book has many subjects.

I only want to display a book once, regardless of how many subjects the book matched.

This image below was the output of the search query I made, the value of the `$search= ""`

[image]

On the second image notice that I search "a" on the search box:
[image]

The book entitled "Special Education assessment: Issues strategies affecting today's classrooms" (see it on the first image; it was being redundant 6 times since the subjects of that book was 6)

Comment: Try to add `->groupBy('books.id')->paginate(20);`

Comment: It just gives me this error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'bisu_ccc_library.books.ISBN' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select distinct `books`.*, `subjects`.`subject` from `books` left join `subjects` on `books`.`id` = `subjects`.`book_id` where `subject` like %a% group by `books`.`id` order by `created_at` desc limit 20 offset 0)

Comment: witch version of laravel do you use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a book only once you have to group by book id (or any other unique column)

```
->groupBy('books.id');
```

Mind you, as mentioned in the MySQL doc [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

> SQL92 and earlier does not permit queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are not named in the GROUP BY clause.

Hence the error message `'bisu_ccc_library.books.ISBN' isn't in GROUP BY`

To bypass this, turn off `strict` in Laravel and everything will work nicely. 
Go to `config/database.php` and in the mysql configuration array, change `strict => true` to `strict => false`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `distinct` for your select

```
$book = Book::latest() 
    ->leftjoin('subjects', 'books.id', '=', 'subjects.book_id') 
    ->select('books.*', 'subjects.subject')
    ->distinct()
    ->where('subject', 'like', '%' .$search. '%')
    ->paginate(20);
```

Just like in regular SQL (which it will translate to) it will "Force the query to only return distinct results." (from [laravel api docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_distinct))

> The SELECT DISTINCT statement is used to return only distinct
>   (different) values.
>
> Inside a table, a column often contains many duplicate values; and
>   sometimes you only want to list the different (distinct) values.
>
> The SELECT DISTINCT statement is used to return only distinct
>   (different) values. - [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Comment: I tried to add distinct as you said but still down worked